# How can I send an error to my svelte file from a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling, svelte, sveltekit

I have a asyncrounous supabase login method in a Javascript file and this function is triggered remotely by a svelte file. If the method returns an error I would like the error to be sent to my svelte file, and then displayed in a paragraph element.

I tried creating a error variable named errorMessage and assigning the error message to it when the function returns the error but when I try to console.log the error after the login method is called in my svelte file it logs the initial value that errorMessage has been assigned.

Svelte:

```
<script>
import { createAccount, login, errorMessage } from '$lib/supabaseClient.js'

login(email, password);
console.log(errorMessage)
</script>
```

JS:

```
export let errorMessage;

export const login = async (email, password) => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
        email,
        password
    })
    errorMessage = error;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try to console.log the error after the login method is called in my svelte file it logs the initial value that errorMessage has been assigned.

This is because `login()` is an `async` function. In your code, the `console.log()` was executed before `login()` was done.

You may get different results by adding an `await` to wait for the `login()` function to complete, first:

```
import { createAccount, login, errorMessage } from '$lib/supabaseClient.js';
await login(email, password);
console.log(errorMessage);
```